# how to show img or png or svg inside option with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, svg

I want to add the image to the angular select option list. I saw some example with `data-image` works inside option. But I didn't make it work.Could someone help me out? The jsffidle is in the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/drt6y0wf/

And I want the image show inside the option list.Is there other way I can do this with pure angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  native select option does not support image inside dropdown. You need construct an emulated ui using other html element, like div and li. For example http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/components/#dropdowns